# get continues reading from continues touch

Tags: android, events

I want to get continues reading from a continues touch down event.
I mean that I want to get event every 0.01 sec.
I've tried to use GestureDetector and I got down, show and long events during a continues
touch. After the long event I don't get any events.
Please help...

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for TouchMotion events in the `Activity`'s [`onTouch()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch%28android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent%29) method.

Comment: 10'x, Done that (look at the code below) but I get no event after down, show and long events. What is the event that I'm looking for?   this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    
    //@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {   
     boolean l_bLocal = true;
     l_bLocal = gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(event);

     return l_bLocal;
    }
   });

Answer (score 0):

Where are you logging the events? The onTouch() handler should be called whenever the user touches the screen. You can do a switch case on the event to determine what the user is doing:

```
switch(event) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
// When user first touches screen 
break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
// When user is dragging, or continuous touch
break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
// When user stops touching
break;
}
```

Comment: 10x, Did that. The problem is thatI want to get readings after a down event occured and no up event. I want to get the size of the touch event in pixels while pressing.